# Bottom sheet dialog fragment dismissed can not show again

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a bottom sheet dialog fragment containing radio buttons. I dismiss the fragment on button checked change. First time the fragment showing without any problem. But after dismissing the fragment, it is not showing when I call `fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragment.getTag());` also getting following warning :

```
W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4e7dce0 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@60a042d
```

Comment: Create a new object of Bottom Sheet Each time .. You seems to using same `fragment` each time..

Comment: recall the new instance method everytime you want to show it

Comment: Can you post some more code before and after you calling fragment.show

Comment: Is it possible to show fragment without creating new instance every time ?